# xrp {"result":{"error":"noNetwork","error_code":17,"error_message":"Not synced to Ripple network.","request":{"command":"fee"},"status":"error"}}

Tags: xrp, rippled

I'm trying to run a rippled non-validator node.
I'm using an 32GB RAM C5 class instance in aws with an external volume - io1 storage with 10000 iops.
I had node reboot for patching and since then it seems fine but it returns

curl --data-binary '{"method": "fee","params": []}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://:5005/
A normal response is like;

```
{"result":{"current_ledger_size":"68","current_queue_size":"0","drops":{"base_fee":"10","median_fee":"5000","minimum_fee":"10","open_ledger_fee":"10"},"expected_ledger_size":"150","ledger_current_index":51375387,"levels":{"median_level":"128000","minimum_level":"256","open_ledger_level":"256","reference_level":"256"},"max_queue_size":"3000","status":"success"}}
```

err;

```
{"result":{"error":"noNetwork","error_code":17,"error_message":"Not synced to Ripple network.","request":{"command":"fee"},"status":"error"}}
```

After reboot though I just get this Not synced error.

When I spin up a node from fresh it has to download 95GB of data at about 1 a day and it gets the same error while I'm waiting.

I'm wondering what I need to do to keep these nodes stable.

```
[server]
port_rpc_admin_local
port_peer
port_ws_admin_local
#port_ws_public
#ssl_key = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
#ssl_cert = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt

[port_rpc_admin_local]
port = 5005
ip = 0.0.0.0
admin = 127.0.0.1
protocol = http

[port_peer]
port = 51235
ip = 0.0.0.0
# alternatively, to accept connections on IPv4 + IPv6, use:
#ip = ::
protocol = peer

[port_ws_admin_local]
port = 6006
ip = 0.0.0.0
admin = 127.0.0.1
protocol = ws

#[port_ws_public]
#port = 6005
#ip = 0.0.0.0
#protocol = wss

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[node_size]
huge

# This is primary persistent datastore for rippled.  This includes transaction
# metadata, account states, and ledger headers.  Helpful information can be
# found here: https://ripple.com/wiki/NodeBackEnd
# delete old ledgers while maintaining at least 2000. Do not require an
# external administrative command to initiate deletion.
[node_db]
type=RocksDB
path=/data01/rippled/db/rocksdb
open_files=2000
filter_bits=12
cache_mb=256
file_size_mb=8
file_size_mult=2
online_delete=120000
advisory_delete=0

# This is the persistent datastore for shards. It is important for the health
# of the ripple network that rippled operators shard as much as practical.
# NuDB requires SSD storage. Helpful information can be found here
# https://ripple.com/build/history-sharding
#[shard_db]
#path=/data01/rippled/db/shards/nudb
#max_size_gb=500

[database_path]
/data01/rippled/db

# This needs to be an absolute directory reference, not a relative one.
# Modify this value as required.
[debug_logfile]
/var/log/rippled/debug.log

[sntp_servers]
time.windows.com
time.apple.com
time.nist.gov
pool.ntp.org

# To use the XRP test network (see https://ripple.com/build/xrp-test-net/),
# use the following [ips] section:
# [ips]
# r.altnet.rippletest.net 51235

# File containing trusted validator keys or validator list publishers.
# Unless an absolute path is specified, it will be considered relative to the
# folder in which the rippled.cfg file is located.
[validators_file]
validators.txt

# Turn down default logging to save disk space in the long run.
# Valid values here are trace, debug, info, warning, error, and fatal
[rpc_startup]
{ "command": "log_level", "severity": "warning" }

# If ssl_verify is 1, certificates will be validated.
# To allow the use of self-signed certificates for development or internal use,
# set to ssl_verify to 0.
[ssl_verify]
1
```

This is my run command:

```
/opt/ripple/bin/rippled --silent --conf /etc/opt/ripple/rippled.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran a C5.xlarge with an io1 storage volume with 10000 iops.

```
/opt/ripple/bin/rippled --net --silent --conf /etc/opt/ripple/rippled.cfg
```

```
[server]
port_rpc_admin_local
port_peer
port_ws_admin_local
#port_ws_public
#ssl_key = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
#ssl_cert = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt

[port_rpc_admin_local]
port = 5005
ip = 0.0.0.0
admin = 127.0.0.1
protocol = http

[port_peer]
port = 51235
ip = 0.0.0.0
# alternatively, to accept connections on IPv4 + IPv6, use:
#ip = ::
protocol = peer

[port_ws_admin_local]
port = 6006
ip = 0.0.0.0
admin = 127.0.0.1
protocol = ws

#[port_ws_public]
#port = 6005
#ip = 0.0.0.0
#protocol = wss

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[node_size]
medium

# This is primary persistent datastore for rippled.  This includes transaction
# metadata, account states, and ledger headers.  Helpful information can be
# found here: https://ripple.com/wiki/NodeBackEnd
# delete old ledgers while maintaining at least 2000. Do not require an
# external administrative command to initiate deletion.
[node_db]
type=RocksDB
path=/data01/rippled/db/rocksdb
open_files=2000
filter_bits=12
cache_mb=256
file_size_mb=8
file_size_mult=2
online_delete=120000
advisory_delete=0

# This is the persistent datastore for shards. It is important for the health
# of the ripple network that rippled operators shard as much as practical.
# NuDB requires SSD storage. Helpful information can be found here
# https://ripple.com/build/history-sharding
#[shard_db]
#path=/data01/rippled/db/shards/nudb
#max_size_gb=500

[database_path]
/data01/rippled/db

# This needs to be an absolute directory reference, not a relative one.
# Modify this value as required.
[debug_logfile]
/var/log/rippled/debug.log

[sntp_servers]
time.windows.com
time.apple.com
time.nist.gov
pool.ntp.org

# To use the XRP test network (see https://ripple.com/build/xrp-test-net/),
# use the following [ips] section:
# [ips]
# r.altnet.rippletest.net 51235

# File containing trusted validator keys or validator list publishers.
# Unless an absolute path is specified, it will be considered relative to the
# folder in which the rippled.cfg file is located.
[validators_file]
validators.txt

# Turn down default logging to save disk space in the long run.
# Valid values here are trace, debug, info, warning, error, and fatal
[rpc_startup]
{ "command": "log_level", "severity": "warning" }

# If ssl_verify is 1, certificates will be validated.
# To allow the use of self-signed certificates for development or internal use,
# set to ssl_verify to 0.
[ssl_verify]
1
```

/etc/init.d/rippled

````
                #
                # rippled -- startup script for rippled
                #
                # chkconfig: - 85 15
                # processname: rippled
                #
                ### BEGIN INIT INFO
                # Provides: rippled
                # Required-Start: $local_fs $remote_fs $network
                # Required-Stop: $local_fs $remote_fs $network
                # Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
                # Default-Stop: 0 1 6
                # Short-Description: start and stop rippled
                ### END INIT INFO
                #
                #
                #PIDFILE="/data01/bitcoin/bitcoind.pid"
                start() {
                        echo -n "Starting rippled: "
                        exec /opt/ripple/bin/rippled --net --conf /etc/opt/ripple/rippled.cfg "$@"
                }

                stop() {
                    echo "shutting down rippled"
                    exec /opt/ripple/bin/rippled stop"
                    RETVAL=$?

                    rm $PIDFILE
                    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f $PIDFILE
                    return $RETVAL
                }

                force_start() {
                        echo -n "Force starting Bitcoind: "
                        echo -n "Starting rippled: "
                        exec /opt/ripple/bin/rippled --net --conf /etc/opt/ripple/rippled.cfg "$@"
                }

                case "$1" in
                    start)
                        start
                        ;;
                    stop)
                        stop
                        ;;
                    restart)
                        stop
                        sleep 30
                        start
                        ;;
                    force-start)
                        force_start
                        ;;
                    *)
                        echo "Usage:  {start|stop|restart|force-start}"
                        exit 1
                        ;;
                esac
                exit $?```
````

Comment: Following this recipe I can get a node running from scratch in minutes. If it seems to be downloading about 1GB a day but gives either Insufficient network mode or not synced to Rippled network... it just isn't ever going to work.

Comment: turns out it was systemd. The restart on failure was conflicting with the way rippled runs threaded processes.